# Google API OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, google-reader

I'm currently using OAuth 2.0 to access Google's reader API.  I have successfully gotten a "code" and "state" returned in the URL.  Right now I'm using a post method to pass in the required parameters in order to receive an access token.  I have been fiddling with it for quite a while and all I've got is:

```
{ "error": "invalid_request" }
```

My code is below:

```
<?php 

session_start();

$code = $_GET['code'];
$state = $_GET['state'];

if ((!is_numeric($state)) || ($state != $_SESSION['state'])) {
    throw new Exception('Error validating state.');
}

$accessTokenExchangeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
$redirectUriPath = '/authentication.php';

$accessTokenExchangeParams = array(
    'code' => $code,
    'client_id' => 'xxxxx',
    'client_secret' => 'xxxxx',
    'redirect_uri' => (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'https://':'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $redirectUriPath,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
    );


$goToUrl = $accessTokenExchangeUrl . '?' . http_build_query($accessTokenExchangeParams);

?> 

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action=<?php echo $goToUrl; ?> method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Click Me!">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the code, client_id, etc. variables as input parameters (in the POST request body), instead of in the query string?  Google examples [demonstrate it that way](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse).

There are security reasons why they shouldn't be in the query string if you're [following the OAuth 2 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-3.2).

Comment: Thanks, I created a custom PHP CURL function to pass my parameters through and everything is working correctly now :)